# Using HTML to output data from my RASPBERRY

Tags: python, flask, request, raspberry-pi

heello

I build a raspberry temperature sensor. It works well. I can catch the temperature. I made a request on my raspberry file to communicate with my pc. But i got an internal server error :

[image]

I can't even go on my root page :

this i my code on my pc :

```
@app.route ('/')
def hello_world():
    measures = []
    query_sensor = models.Sensor.query.all ()
    print (query_sensor)
    for sensor in query_sensor:
        query_mes = models.Measure.query.filter(models.Measure.sensor_id == sensor.id).all ()
        measures += [{'serial':sensor.serial, 'measures':query_mes}]
    print (measures)
    return render_template('measures.html', data= query_mes)


@app.route('/data/measure', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page_data_measure ():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.to_dict()
        print(data)
        if 'serial' in data and 'value' in data and 'date' in data:
            # recherche le capteur
            sensor = None
            query_sensor = models.Sensor.query.filter(models.Sensor.serial == data['serial']).first()
            print (query_sensor)
            if query_sensor is None:
                sensor = models.Sensor (data['serial'])
                database.db_session.add(sensor)
                database.db_session.commit()
            else:
                sensor = query_sensor
            mes = models.Measure (datetime.strptime(data['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), float(data['value']), sensor.id)

            database.db_session.add (mes)
            database.db_session.commit ()

        else:
            return 'Bad value', 422

    return render_template('temperatures.html', data=mes)
```

this is the code with an api on the raspberry(writeme.py) :

```
import requests
import datetime
import time


from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor
sensor = W1ThermSensor()
print ("demarrer avec requete")



while True:
    temperature = sensor.get_temperature()
    data = {'date':datetime.datetime.now(), 'serial':'12345678', 'value':temperature}
    r = requests.post("http://192.168.137.1:5000/data/measure", data=data)
    print(r)
    print("The temperature is %s celsius" % temperature)
    time.sleep(1)
```

this is request result message :
[image]

the command that i run are : flask run -h 0.0.0.0
and on my raspberry are : python run writeme.py

thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have an error when you start you flask server ?

Comment: @AlexisG no error when i run flask run -h 0.0.0.0 : https://www.linkpicture.com/q/flask-serv.png

Comment: And if you go to `0.0.0.0:5000/data/measure` ?

Comment: the webpage told me : This site is inaccessible
"
The web page at http://0.0.0.0:5000/data/measure may be temporarily inaccessible or may have been moved permanently to a different web address."

Comment: Oh  "-h 0.0.0.0" means that the OS is listening on all public IPs. Didn't know that !  Your API in running on "http://192.168.137.1:5000" and not the default "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" ?

Comment: yes exactly """

Comment: and if i put http://192.168.137.1:5000/data/measure : i got a blank page :https://www.linkpicture.com/q/blank-page.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221267/discussion-between-alexisg-and-lionel-symr).